# DataTables rowreorder working, but data still not in new order

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I'm using DataTables' reorder function, and it is working, but when I want to get back the data from it, the data is in the original order.

I pass the elements to the table in array, the first column contains the sequence number

```
dt.row.add([snum, ..., ..., ...]);
```

I have tried several options, the drag and drop working, but the data is not reordering with it...

Comment: Having the same issue. Tried everything the docs suggested, but still printing original order of row.